# Azure DevOps task to kick off another release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In our Azure DevOps deployment we have one "master" release pipeline that generates and runs "child" pipelines. The child pipelines are never run directly.

Currently we kick off the child pipelines using a Powershell script in the master pipeline, but I was wondering if there is a built in task that can do this automatically? I've taken a look at the task list, but nothing jumps out. It's fine if there isn't one, but wanted to ask in case I missed something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe there is one built in by default, so sticking with your Posh script might be the best bet.

I have found/seen this extension before: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergiibomko.vsts-trigger

Seems like that may do what you want with a small amount of configuration, but it is a third party made extension without a ton of reviews/reputation.

IMO, if your powershell script is doing what you need currently without any pain, stick with that :)

Comment: Agreed. I'd rather either use built in tasks or own the scripts that do what I need.

Comment: Hopefully they add this as a built in soon - makes a lot of sense as a use case!

Answer (score 1):

***The answer has changed with the latest updates to Azure DevOps.***

> You should be able to use multi-stage pipelines or jobs that are part of  yaml pipelines.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/intelligent-productivity-and-collaboration-from-anywhere/

Refer below to get an idea on how to do this: https://github.com/venura9/azure-devops-yaml

As long as you are using your `dependsOn' correctly you should be good.

Answer (score -1):

There is not an out-of-the-box task but in the marketplace you can find [VSTS Creare Release Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=venzhyk.vnzk-vsts-tasks) that do exactly what you want.

[image]